# How to inject HTML via Tag-Manager on specific place?

Tags: replace, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have to inject a Codesnippet on a specific place in a html.

For example:

```
<section class="newsletter">
content content content
</section>
```

Now I want the Tagmanager to inject on this section another code instead of the section newsletter.

```
<div class="injector">
content content content
</div>
```

Ive tried some scripts but none of them showed the content. The custom html has been loaded, but did not replace the section.

How should i do this?
Thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it this way:

```
    <script>
      jQuery('div#container_to_hang_on').append('<div id="injector"></div>');
   </script>
```

But you @Kemen Paulos Plaza said its not recommended at all. Why? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a custom script to append the content in an HTML tag
for example and with the provided data, using Jquery.

The only thing that you have to care about is that the function is executed, in this case i'm using a [anonymous function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp)

```
<script>
(function(){
var div = document.createElement('div');
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1 = $(h1).text('tille');
div = $(div).text('content content content')
div = $(div).attr('class','injection')
div = $(div).append(h1)
$('.post-text').append(div)
}
)()
</script>
```

Comment: Thx! 
But what if I want du inject not only the content, when I want to inject the  whole div?

Comment: I extend a little more the answer hoping it fix better with your needs, is also possible to use $('.css-selector').append('<div class="injector">content content content<div>') , but this is not recommended at all.